# Service Fabric app Kestrel cert rotation on new cert

Tags: certificate, azure-service-fabric, kestrel-http-server, service-fabric-stateless

I am having a Service Fabric stateless app.

Using the following code for ServiceInstanceListener:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
            {
                new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                    new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                    {
                        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");
                        
                        return new WebHostBuilder()
                                    .UseKestrel(opt =>
                                    {
                                        int port = serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("ServiceEndpoint").Port;
                                        opt.Listen(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port, listenOptions =>
                                        {
                                            X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateFromStore();
                                            listenOptions.UseHttps(cert);
                                            listenOptions.NoDelay = true;
                                        });
```

Function GetCertificateFromStore:

```
        private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore()
        {
               string subjectCommonName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("certsubject");
                X509Certificate2 certForApp = null;
                using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
                {
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                    var certCollection = store.Certificates;

                    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/cluster-security-certificate-management
                    foreach (var enumeratedCert in certCollection)
                    {
                        if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(subjectCommonName, enumeratedCert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, forIssuer: false))
                          && DateTime.Now < enumeratedCert.NotAfter
                          && DateTime.Now >= enumeratedCert.NotBefore)
                        {
                            if (certForApp == null)
                            {
                                certForApp = enumeratedCert;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // the Service Fabric runtime will find and select the most recently issued matching certificate (largest value of the 'NotBefore' property). Note this is a change from previous versions of the Service Fabric runtime.
                                if (enumeratedCert.NotBefore > certForApp.NotBefore)
                                {
                                    certForApp = enumeratedCert;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (certForApp == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Could not find a match for a certificate with subject 'CN={subjectCommonName}'.");
                    }

                    return certForApp;

}
```

In case a new version of cert is installed on the VMSS(**say after cert rotation**), how should the stateless app pick up the new cert **without service restart**.
*In case the service is restarted, the latest cert is picked up.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code like this:

```
new WebHostBuilder()
   .UseKestrel(options =>
{
   options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);
   options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
   {
      listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
      {
         httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (context, dnsName) =>
         {
            //return cached certificate, invalidate if needed (e.g. check periodically)
            if(_cachedCertificate is null)
            {
              _cachedCertificate = GetCertificateFromStore();
              return _cachedCertificate;
            }
         }
     }
}
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.https.httpsconnectionadapteroptions.servercertificateselector?view=aspnetcore-2.1)